# call Activity when click button on core game LibGDX

Tags: android, button, android-activity, interface, libgdx

I have a button on Core game. I want when i click button, a Activity will run. I think i can use Interface but it do not work.

```
buttonPost.addListener(new ClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                myGameCallback.startActivity();

            }
        });
```

Here is my interface

```
 public interface MyGameCallback{
            public void startActivity();
        }

        private MyGameCallback myGameCallback;

        public void setMyGameCallback(MyGameCallback callback){
            myGameCallback=callback;

        }
```

And android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements Main.MyGameCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        Main main=new Main();
        main.setMyGameCallback(this);

        initialize(main, config);
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Post.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: Looks like it should work fine. Did you set your Stage as the game's input listener? Also, you should use EventListener instead of ClickListener for Buttons.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you. I set My stage as the game's inputlistener. And i change ClickListener to EventListener but it still do not work. I don't understand, can you help me?

Comment: You need to clarify "do not work". Can you debug and see if your method is even getting called?

Answer (score 3):

The Interface way to implement some native android functionality in LIBGDX works as follows.
First of all why your Main class implement screen? As far as I know the Main Class should implement Game. Screen is different then main class. 
So here you go for Interface.

```
 public interface MyGameCallback{
            public void startActivity();
        }
```

On AndroidLauncher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements
    MyGameCallback{

// provide implementation of startActivity(); method. 

}
```

Finally your main Game class should go like

```
public class MainGame extends Game {


    public MyGameCallback myGameCallback;



    public MainGame(MyGameCallback myGameCallback) {
        super();
        this.myGameCallback = myGameCallback; // initialize in constructor

    }
```

Finally on the button in game where you want to start your activity do it like.

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen { 

private MainGame mygame;

    public MainmenuScreen(MainGame game) { // initiaize maingame class so that you can call Interface method by its reference 

this.mygame = game;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////

Finally on your button do call the method

```
buttonPost=new TextButton("Post",skin);
            buttonPost.pad(20);
            buttonPost.addListener(new EventListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean handle(Event event) {
                    mygame.myGameCallback.startActivity();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

If You call it by just Interface name it wont work.

Comment: thanks Aiman Batul, but when i debug your code, mygame.myGameCallback= null

Comment: Check my answer again. I have explained that mygame is the type of your game main class that extends game. unless and untill you dont initialize its object in every other class constructor, you cannot call anything by its reference. Null can only be there if you have not done so.

Comment: this was my mistake, the first i forgot initialize my activity on Manifest, then i fixed something, when i saw my mistake, every thing was so hard. LOL